# Check connection time out, preferable check using long elapsedTicks or DateTime elapsedTime?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, connection, tcpclient

TCP server send data to buffer and MainForm receive data from buffer and do some processing

I have a parameter to check the time on lastDataReceive (from TCP) on the buffer.

I also have a paramter to check the time on dataReceiveNow (from buffer) on the MainForm.

Now, I want to calculate the elasped time, if lastDataReceive (from TCP) - dataReceiveNow (from buffer) > 60 seconds, then it will prompt MessageBox.Show(" Connection Time out ");

I have two method on doing it, but I don't know which one gives the best result or actually both are the same?

**1st method:** Get the elasped time using DateTime format and check the condition of 1 second

```
private void CheckConnectionTimeOut()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(receiver.LastDataReceivedTime).TotalSeconds > 60)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Out");
    }
    else
    {
        // do what ever
    }
}
```

**2nd method:** Get the elasped time by calculating the elapsedTicks

```
private void CheckConnectionTimeOut()
{
    long dataTimeOut = (long)TimeSpan.FromTicks(receiver.LastDataTick - dataReceiveTickNow).TotalSeconds;

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(dataTimeOut);

    if (dt.Second > 60)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Out");
    }
    else
    { 
         // do what ever           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those are recommended, and [can actually be dangerous](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Instead, use a `Stopwatch` class to measure elapsed duration.  Reference [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).